# Are Microsoft graph REST APIs responses same as Microsoft live sdk? As we know that live sdk now decommissioned

Tags: java, rest, microsoft-graph-api

As Microsoft live sdk depreciated, I don't know it's responses and I need to migrate my application to Microsoft graph so I want know old responses so that easily I can compare old and new responses and accordingly do changes in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I am a lead on Microsoft Graph. Yes, you should be moving to calls on graph.microsoft.com. We do not provide documentation on what the api mapping is between the live SDK is to Microsoft Graph SDK is.

The docs for Microsoft Graph are all here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/

and we have details on how to get started with our SDKs here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview

I'd be interested to understand how many different apis you're querying and happy to help with the mapping. The learn section of the docs should help yyou narrow down the APIs you'll need to call. For instance, anything on the Users profile would be here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/azuread-users-concept-overview

Comment: Actually in live sdk we were using url "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive" but response we don't know as earlier our developer had not documented responses. And in same way now in microsoft graph we are using url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive", so want to know which url I should use. Like this some more live sdk url are there which we want to map with new urls.

Comment: Sorry can you clairfy, its not entirely clear what your ask is. graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive is the correct url to use. If you go to our docs you can see what the equivalent SDK codde would be to use for this URL too.